# Magento2 : How to disable product image slider on detail page?

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento-2.0, slider, fotorama-slider

I want to disable product image slider on product detail page, only in desktop and tablet view. also all product images visible in same.

other all images functionality must work like images open in full screen.

Display All images vertically at the same time. show all images one by one in vertical order.

Note: Only disable slider which is displayed only one product image.

Comment: This is pure css.. It does not have any relation with magento

Comment: In Magento product images use fotorama.js and structure generated by js then how we can manage images structure by css ? please check first.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure slider in view.xml file. It located in `/theme_folder/etc/view.xml`. There you can write vars for gallery. For luma theme it looks like this

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">

    <!-- Gallery and magnifier theme settings. Start -->
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
        <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Gallery navigation loop (true/false) -->
        <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false) -->
        <var name="arrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
        <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
        <var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
        <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
        <var name="navarrows">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off on the thumbs navigation sides (true/false) -->
        <var name="navtype">slides</var> <!-- Sliding type of thumbnails (slides/thumbs) -->
        <var name="transition">
            <var name="effect">slide</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
            <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
        </var>
        <var name="fullscreen">
            <var name="nav">thumbs</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
            <var name="loop">true</var> <!-- Fullscreen navigation loop (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="keyboard">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off keyboard arrows navigation (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false/null) -->
            <var name="caption">false</var> <!-- Display alt text as image title (true/false) -->
            <var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!--Sliding direction of thumbnails in full screen(horizontal/vertical)  -->
            <var name="thumbwidth">150</var> <!-- Width of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="thumbheight">150</var> <!-- Height of thumbnails in fullscreen -->
            <var name="navigation_carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            <var name="transition">
                <var name="effect">dissolve</var> <!-- Sets transition effect for slides changing (slide/crossfade/dissolve) -->
                <var name="duration">500</var> <!-- Sets transition duration in ms -->
                <var name="carousel">true</var> <!-- Display navigation thumbs as carousel (true/false) -->
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes i know already but how can disable slider and show all image same ?

Comment: You can try set all options to "false" or override Magento_Catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml template and manually display images.  You can use method getGalleryImages for getting all images

Comment: Yes i have idea for the display manually but if display it manually then other images related functionality does not work like image on click, all images open with full screen etc.

Comment: For those wanting to remove the magnifier you can do so with: `<var name="magnifier">
    ...
    <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    ...
</var>`

Comment: I couldn't find such such lines in    vendor\magento\module-catalog\etc\view.xml ...    Could u please tell the correct path for this view.xml

Comment: Atlast i found the folder..But i don't know which part to edit..to move gallery image from bottom to left side vertical align..

Comment: I tried all the options but not able to disabled slider.disabled slider doesn't me to remove slider images but it means only remove slider & media images will show without any slider.you can check this post for more clarification https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238130/magento2-remove-slider-of-gallery-images-on-product-detail-page
so please share the solution if you got.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code in your catalog_product_view.xml file

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.media" remove="true" />
```

hope this helps