# Magento2 remove slider of gallery images on product detail page

Tags: product, magento2.2, product-images, gallery-image

I'm using Magento2.2.5 Version, On product detail page by default gallery images
showing in the slider.

Here is the screenshot for the same:-

http://nimb.ws/YrIb2P

**But I want to show, gallery images without any slider.**

You can see below-expected result screesnhot:-

http://nimb.ws/ZA6vMD

I tried to modify view.xml as well as the gallery.phtml but not able to get my expected result.

So please help me.

Comment: Any update please?

Comment: Did anyone find out how to do this?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I've used **"MSP_LightGallery"** Ext. which is available on GitHub.you can download here and modify according to your requirement:-

https://github.com/magespecialist/m2_MSP_LightGallery

Thanks!!!