# Magento:2 I want to display product image in 1 column vertically instead of using default Fortorama.js. I want to remove slider

Tags: product, configurable-product, catalog, fotorama-slider

I am facing this issue ..I don't want to display product images in default slider which is coming from `fotorama.js` 
I want them to displayed as one by one without slider

[image: current]

What should I do

```
    $images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
$mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
    return $block->isMainImage($img);
}));

if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
    $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
}

$helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
$mainImageData = $mainImage ?
    $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
    $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');

?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                 "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please check this. It may help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114114/magento2-how-to-disable-product-image-slider-on-detail-page

Comment: I have checked it already didn't help for me